# Cache-Control: no-cache in request header response does not replace previously cached response until page reload in Safari

Tags: ios, angularjs, http, safari, browser-cache

I am using AngularJS in Safari and in a hybrid iOS application.

I have an HTTP response which is being cached for 10 minutes using the following headers. This response gets cached. We will call this Response A in Step 1.

`Cache-Control:public, max-age=600`

This gets cached correctly, and after 10 minutes, a new request will be made.

However, I have logic which will cause the client side to ignore the cache due to certain events which would change the response if requested again. When these events occur, I made a new HTTP request with the following request headers to bypass the cache and get a new response. These headers are the only differences between the requests. This is Step 2.

`Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: {Current date time}`

This response (Response B) is the same as Response A, except that it has different information in the body. The response headers are identical, other than the Date response header. Making this request successfully bypasses the cache and retrieves the new resource from the server and all is well.

However, this new response does not replace the previous response in the cache. For example, if I navigated to a different page (which does not cause a page reload since my app is a SPA using AngularJS), and then navigated back to the page that makes the same request that was made in Step 1, it gets Response A instead of Response B. I expect Response B to be returned instead.

This is only a problem in Safari. Chrome and IE work correctly in that any future requests will return Response B.

However in Safari, if I do a page reload (`⌘ + R`), it will ignore the cache completely, and make a brand new request to the same resource. If I hit enter in the Safari URL bar, it does not ignore the cache, but still uses Response A.

How do I get Safari to behave like other browsers and replace cached responses when making new requests which bypass the cache?

To summarize:

1. Make a request without setting Cache-Control headers in reqeust. Get response with Cache-Control headers called Response A.
2. Make new request with explicit Cache-Control, Pragma, and Expires request headers which bypass request, get updated Response B.
3. Navigate away and then back, makes a new request just like in step 1. I expect to get Response B, but get Response A instead. Response B in Step 2 does not replace Response A, even though response headers are mostly identical (except Date header) and the body is different.